# How to link IIS directory to installed application

Tags: c#, iis, virtual-directory

My team at work has a Web Page application (Asp.net). It is installed on the system by the msi Installer. We are working on external tool (C# application) to manage many instances on the same server. Information about single instance I have found in the registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.
However I am not able to find how the particular instance is mapped to relevant directory in IIS. Each hint will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish, but there are many ways to manage IIS - Powershell, appcmd, Microsoft.Web.Administration (.net), but they all basically manipulate the [ApplicationHost.config](https://www.iis.net/configreference) file.

Comment: everything about where directories and bindings are mapped in IIS would be found in this file `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

Comment: Answering to the first question: " It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish". In the other words: I want to find a connection between app installed in the system (visable in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features) and relevant VirtualDirectory, The applicationHost.config can be usefull but only for single instance. When There are two the same instances in the system I cannot distinguish them in applicationHost.config as it contains only Product Name which are the same. The best way will be find the relevant VirtualDirectory base on the GUID (Product code) from registry.